# Gmail Service in Symfony2

Tags: php, api, symfony, gmail, composer-php

I need to use the Gmail service in my project in Symfony2. I installed the Google Suite via composer but I noticed that it is really too much for what I do. I need only the services and Gmail API. Is there a way to just download the Service Gmail and not all of Google ever via composer?

Thanks for the possible response.

Comment: Why? Use the library and use the parts you need. Programming has nothing to do with your OCD.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to just send emails from gmail using your program or do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to use the Gmail service in my project in Symfony2.

I'd suggest using an existing package:

- [fourlabs/gmail-doctrine-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/fourlabs/gmail-doctrine-bundle) or
- [adevait/gmail-wrapper](https://packagist.org/packages/adevait/gmail-wrapper)

Both packages use [google/apiclient](https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient) interally to access the Google API.

> I installed the Google Suite via composer but I noticed that it is really too much for what I do.

What is Google Suite? Which package are you referring to?

> I need only the services and Gmail API. Is there a way to just download the Service Gmail and not all of Google ever via composer?

Composer fetches development dependencies. That doesn't mean that you have to ship all of the fetched stuff. You can reduce the size of your project by deleting unnecessary parts (before you package for deployment).